# unable to install guard-livereload on windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, guard

I am running **Windows 8** and trying to install `gem install guard-livereload`

- Windows 8 64BIT
- Ruby 200-x64
- Ruby DebKit 64 Bit

I keep getting an error

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lssl... no
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
creating Makefile

make
generating rubyeventmachine-x64-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option '-Wdeclaration-after-statement' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:26:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
In file included from project.h:149:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
In file included from c:\ruby200-x64\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:12:0,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h:60,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:153,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from em.h:24,
                 from project.h:150,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
c:\ruby200-x64\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sys/types.h:68:16: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef _pid_t pid_t'
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:97:13: error: 'pid_t' has a previous declaration as 'typedef int pid_t'
In file included from project.h:150:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:84:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:85:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:86:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:88:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:89:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:90:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:91:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:93:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:99:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:116:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:125:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
In file included from project.h:151:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
ed.h: In member function 'void EventableDescriptor::SetSocketInvalid()':
ed.h:43:40: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
In file included from project.h:154:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h: At global scope:
eventmachine.h:46:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:47:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:48:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:50:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:65:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:66:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:67:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:68:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
In file included from project.h:154:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:103:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:105:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:108:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1
```

EDIT
Running **gem install eventmachine --pre**

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lssl... no
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
creating Makefile

make
generating rubyeventmachine-x64-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option '-Wdeclaration-after-statement' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:26:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
In file included from project.h:149:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
In file included from c:\ruby200-x64\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:12:0,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h:60,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:153,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from c:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from em.h:24,
                 from project.h:150,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
c:\ruby200-x64\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sys/types.h:68:16: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef _pid_t pid_t'
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:97:13: error: 'pid_t' has a previous declaration as 'typedef int pid_t'
In file included from project.h:150:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:84:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:85:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:86:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:88:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:89:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:90:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:91:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:93:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:99:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:116:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
em.h:125:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
In file included from project.h:151:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
ed.h: In member function 'void EventableDescriptor::SetSocketInvalid()':
ed.h:43:40: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
In file included from project.h:154:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h: At global scope:
eventmachine.h:46:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:47:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:48:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:50:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:65:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:66:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:67:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:68:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
In file included from project.h:154:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:103:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:105:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
eventmachine.h:108:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

According to [this issue](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/406), eventmachine can't compile in ruby 2.0 (both x64 and x32). The only environment I can run guard-livereload is Ruby 1.9.3 with tdm-32-4.5.2 DevKit for now.

After setup

```
$ gem install guard guard-livereload wdm
```

should do the work.

---

I've build guard and guard-live successfully on 1.9.2 long time ago.
You need some gems like `win32console`.

Comment: Thank you for feedback TaianSu! I've just tried the first command but that itself is throwing an error (edited post)

Comment: upps. sorry I don't have a pc nearby. I'll get one and try these couple days. :(